# Existence of a measurable function

Tags: integration, measure-theory

The question is

> Let $\theta>0$ fixed. Is there a measurable function $h:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$
>   such that $\int_0^1h(x)x^{\theta-1}dx=1$ and $h$ is independent of
>   $\theta$?

Could you check my negative proof?

Let us suppose there is $h$. Since $h$ is independent of $\theta$, then $\int_0^1h(x)x^{\theta-1}dx=1$ for all $\theta>0$. Now, for $\theta=1$ we get $h$ is integrable.

Let $f:\Omega\times J\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,\theta)=h(x)x^{\theta-1}$, with $\Omega=[0,1]$ and $J=(2,e+1)$.

- For $x\in\Omega$ fixed, it is easy to show that $f(x,\cdot)$ is absolutely continuous function.
- For $\theta\in J$ fixed, it is easy to show that $f(\cdot,\theta)$ is measurable and integrable.

Moreover, $|\frac{\partial f(x,\theta)}{\partial\theta}|=|h(x)\log(\theta-1)x^{\theta-1}|\le|h(x)|$ for all $(x,\theta)\in \Omega\times J$ and $h$ is integrable in $\Omega$.

Thus, we can differentiate both sides of $\int_0^1g(x)x^{\theta-1}dx=1$ getting $\log(\theta-1)\int_0^1h(x)x^{\theta-1}dx=0$. Therefore $\log(\theta-1)=0$ for all $\theta\in J$. This contradiction shows that $h$ doesn't exist.

Comment: What does $h$ independent of $\theta$ mean? Should the same $h$ work for all $\theta>0$?

Comment: $h$  is only a function of $x$; nor of $\theta$. For example, $h(x)=\theta$ satisfies integral condition, but depends on $\theta$. Now, since $h$ is independent of $\theta$, the same h must be used for every value of $\theta$

Comment: So why say "$\theta$ fixed" at the beginning?